# Why isn't Options[] finding all options?

Tags: plotting, options

I've created a plot with 3 non default options.  See below.  I would like to list these options using the `Option[]` function.  When calling Options on the the plot, it lists a number of options including one that I changed but not including the other two.

```
In[144]:= Options[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Dashing[.01], 
  AxesLabel -> {"mtempx", "mtempy"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]]



Out[144]= {DisplayFunction -> Identity, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 Axes -> {True, True}, AxesLabel -> {"mtempx", "mtempy"}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, DisplayFunction :> Identity, 
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 GridLines -> {None, None}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[
GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
 Method -> {"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic, 
   "DefaultMeshStyle" -> AbsolutePointSize[6], 
   "ScalingFunctions" -> None}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-1., 1.}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], 
    Scaled[0.05]}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}
```

1. This seems random to me, but I'm sure its not.  Can someone explain what is going on?
2. How do I get all options to appear?
3. Better yet, how do I get all options that I changed to appear and none of the other options?

Comment: You are seeing all the options of the `Graphics` expression returned by evaluating `Plot`.

Comment: You just have wrong expectations. In general, you can't see the options you passed to a function, in the result of that function's execution. Why should you? It could be e.g. a number, a list, whatever, leaving no trace of the initial arguments. In the case of Plot, what you get as a result is an expression, interpreted in a special way by the FrontEnd. This is why *some* of the options you pass, may survive and enter the result. But this is a pure accident - it just so happens in this case. You shouldn't count on this. Reconstructing passed arguments from a result is not possible generally.

Comment: An example is that `PlotStyle->Dashing[.01]` gets placed in a directive `Directive[Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
 AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Dashing[0.01]]`

Comment: I didn't realize this.  A very informative answer.  Thank you.